# Getting problem authenticationProvider in jwt authorization

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am getting error in configure method of SecurityConfig class whose code is here:

```
package com.sumit.Security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

import com.sumit.Repo.UserRepository;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;



    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
        }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
           http
           // remove csrf and state in session because in jwt we do not need them
           .csrf().disable()
           .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
           .and()
           .addFilter(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
           .addFilter(new JwtAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(),userRepository))
           .authorizeRequests()
           // configure access rules
           .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
           .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
           .antMatchers("/user").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER")
           .antMatchers("/management").hasAnyRole("MANAGER","ADMIN")
           .antMatchers("/page1").hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN","ACCESS_PAGE1")
           .antMatchers("/page2").hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN","ACCESS_PAGE2")
           .anyRequest().authenticated();
//           .and()
//           .formLogin()
//           .loginPage("/login")
//           .usernameParameter("username")
//           .passwordParameter("password").successForwardUrl("/welcome")
//          .permitAll();


    }

    @Bean
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(this.userDetailsService);
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }



    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

in above code, error lies here `auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());`
code is getting compiled fine but due to this i am getting 403 forbidden. Flow is getting broken here

**JwtAutheticationFilter class is here**

```
package com.sumit.Security;

import static com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.Algorithm.HMAC512;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import com.auth0.jwt.JWT;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.sumit.Repo.UserRepository;


public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public JwtAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        LoginModel credentials = null;
    try {
            credentials = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), LoginModel.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                credentials.getUsername(), credentials.getPassword(), new ArrayList<>());

        Authentication auth = authenticationManager.authenticate(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
        return auth;
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain,
            Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        UserPrincipal principal = (UserPrincipal) authResult.getPrincipal();
        String token = JWT.create()
                .withSubject(principal.getUsername())
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + JWTProperties.EXPIRATION_TIME))
                .sign(HMAC512(JWTProperties.SECRET.getBytes()));

        response.addHeader(JWTProperties.HEADER_STRING, JWTProperties.TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
    }




}
```

**JwtAuthorizationFilter class is here**

```
package com.sumit.Security;

import static com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.Algorithm.HMAC512;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;

import com.auth0.jwt.JWT;
import com.sumit.Repo.UserRepository;

public class JwtAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {
    @Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;
    public JwtAuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager,UserRepository userRepository
            ) {
        super(authenticationManager);

    }

    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // Read the Authorization header, where the JWT token should be
        String header = request.getHeader(JWTProperties.HEADER_STRING);

        // If header does not contain BEARER or is null delegate to Spring impl and exit
        if (header == null || !header.startsWith(JWTProperties.TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        // If header is present, try grab user principal from database and perform authorization
        Authentication authentication = getUsernamePasswordAuthentication(request);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        // Continue filter execution
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private Authentication getUsernamePasswordAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String token = request.getHeader(JWTProperties.HEADER_STRING)
                .replace(JWTProperties.TOKEN_PREFIX,"");

        if (token != null) {
            // parse the token 
            String userName = JWT.require(HMAC512(JWTProperties.SECRET.getBytes()))
                    .build()
                    .verify(token)
                    .getSubject();

               if (userName != null) {
                User user = userRepository.findByUsername(userName);
                UserPrincipal principal = new UserPrincipal(user);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userName, null, principal.getAuthorities());
                return auth;
            }
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

User registration process is working fine but authentication is not working because of above mentioned code.
I am using **postman** to verify it.
Don't know what trouble i am facing and totally frustrated.

Comment: if you run the application with spring security debug logging, it will tell you what it is failing on.

Comment: unsuccessfulAuthentication method is getting called at place of successful authentication. It is the problem i come to know using debugging

Comment: i think you missunderstood, `logging.level.org.springframework.security: DEBUG` in your application.properties will show you the debug logging for spring security and it will tell you what goes on under the hood.

Comment: yes i understood but i am not able to get any solution. Problem is that it is calling ```unsuccessfulAuthentication``` method at place of ```successfulAuthentication```, while debugging authanticated = true but then also m not getting why it is calling ```unsuccessfulAuthentication``` method

Comment: @Toerktumlare .... you literally saved my life.... I was pulling my hair out for two hours trying to figure out why my authentication was failing and then I did what you said and to my horror I discovered that authentication was failing because the account was locked forgot to return true when implementing userDetails interface since default is false. Thanks a million!